# Dynamically populate a dropdownlist in asp C# using a eval result

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm creating a shopping cart. I have a dropdownlist, inside a listview. I want to simply add a range of numbers according to eval("stock") for 0 up to stock or 10.

```
<% int range = atoi(eval("..")) // don't know the correct conversion syntax, not to that point yet..
if(range >10)
 range = 10
for(i = 0; i < range; i++){
 dropdown1.Item.append( new listitem...)
} 
%>
```

I've tried to do it with a function call, but I couldn't figure it out. I tried it in both a script tag and in the cs file.

Any help I could get pointing me in the right direction would be awesome. I'm new, and I've been researching this for hours now. 2 50 dollar books and they aren't any help in these listview template items..

```
     <AlternatingItemTemplate>
            <span style="">
            <asp:Label ID="productNameLabel" runat="server" 
                Text='<%# Eval("productName") %>' />
            <br />
            <asp:Image runat="server" height = "300" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("img") %>'></asp:Image>
            <br />
            Description:<br />
            <asp:Label ID="itemNotesLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("itemNotes") %>' />
            <br />

            stock:
            <asp:Label ID="stockLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("stock") %>' />
            <br />
            price:
            <asp:Label ID="priceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# "$"+ Eval("price")+".00" %>' />
            <br />

            Quantitiy:<asp:DropDownList id="DropDownList1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList> 

            <br />

            <asp:LinkButton id="addPro" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("productNo") %>' onCommand ="addPro_Click">Add To Cart</asp:LinkButton>
            <br /><br /><br />
<br /></span>
        </AlternatingItemTemplate>
```

Comment: I'm new to C# and asp. I know C/++, java, php, etc well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle `ItemDataBound` event of `ListView` to populate the `DropDownList` controls which are added into each item.

Demo:

markup (.aspx) code

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <p>
        <asp:Label ID="stock" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Stock") %>'></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="stockQty" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
    </p>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

code-behind (.cs)

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Stock { get; set; }
}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        List<Foo> fooList = new List<Foo>()
        {
                new Foo(){ Stock=3},
                new Foo(){ Stock=5}
        };
        ListView1.ItemDataBound += (sa, ea) =>
            {
                int stock = int.Parse((ea.Item.FindControl("Stock") as Label).Text);
                DropDownList stockQty = ea.Item.FindControl("StockQty") as DropDownList;

                for (int i = 0; i <= stock; i++)
                    stockQty.Items.Add(i.ToString());
            };

        ListView1.DataSource = fooList;
        ListView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Both answers were very good, but the other did not actually ever gets launched.. This of course helps me a lot with all the other controls I need to modify. I like how it get's the label which is going to make my function to create the query bar a lot easier to add more data. Though I do find the whole "foolist" part a bit confusing. I'm guessing those are default entries? I'm sure I'll figure it out as I play with it. Thanks again! Oh I did have to add a Null Check (don't worry I found it right away), as it's dynamically created list, and at start there isn't said dropdown control.

Answer (score 1):

In my example I assume you have a datakey of ProductId for the ListView to find the specific Stock. I have added the OnItemDataBound Method which I use in the code behind to populate the dropdownlist.

**Markup**

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvStock" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="lvStock_ItemDataBound" .... >
```

**Code Behind**

```
 protected void lvStock_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
 {

       if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem) 
       {
           // Get the Product Id (or whatever ID it is)
           ListView listView = sender as ListView;
           int index = e.Item.DataItemIndex;
           DataKey dataKey = listView.DataKeys[index];
           int productId = Convert.ToInt32(dataKey["ProductId"]);

           // Get the stock value from your DB or wherever you get it from
           int stock = GetStockById(productId);


           if (stock > 10)
               stock = 10;

           // Get the stock drop down list
           DropDownList ddlListStock = (DropDownList )e.Item.FindControl("DropDownList1");

           // add the values to the drop down list
           for (int i = 0; i <= stock; i++)
           {
                ddlListStock.Items.Add(i.ToString());
           }
       }
  }
```

Comment: This answer is very informative. Though for some reason the code never got executed. I tested to be sure by assigning a new label, and having it rename it. (in case the queries was getting nothing). I do find the database controls very interesting for future use.